# Safari not rendering margin-top % values like other browsers

Tags: html, css, browser, safari, responsive-design

I have asked this question before, but thought I'll be clearer. It seems that `margin-top` in % value does not display the same on Safari, as it does on Chrome, Firefox and IE. In px it displays correctly and `margin-left` % also.

Here is an example to make comparisons: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chuck_y/ASzcZ/)

```
* {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
 }

.A {
   background-color: blue;
   height: 200px;
   position:relative;
 }

.B {
   left: 50px;
   margin-top:15%;
   width:20px;
   height:20px;
   background-color: red;
   position:absolute;
}
```

I really need to use a % value on `margin-top` as it is for a responsive design feature. Using `top` does not scale the object according to the window size.

Are there known issues, and if so (probably asking a big thing) a way to only target Safari as a browser so I can have custom values for the style sheet?

Comment: What's your Safari version? it works on me. Btw, if you want to scale the object according to window size you can use `relative` with `top`

Comment: latest version. Even if you open up two browsers side by side ? The red block is on a different position when comparing..

Comment: You're right Chrome arranges the position according to window size, but safari arranges the pos according to the container. I think Safari works correct others work wrong because the position is `absolute`. I think you should change the way you're working. [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/VR52j/) works same on chrome and safari.

Comment: I need to use `margin-top` as the object scales correctly in relation to its width upon resize as displayed [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fsR6A/)

Comment: I think safari is wrong: margin % :'A <percentage> relative to the width of the containing block.' - [mozilla developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin). In my example above it acts like a `top` property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, according to the W3C standards, margins defined using percentages should be calculated *with respect to the **width** of the containing block*.

Ref: (http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/box.html#margin-properties)

However, it appears that Safari calculates top/bottom margin percentages *with respect to the **height** of the containing block*, which makes more logical sense, but is nevertheless incorrect as far as W3 standards go.

I don't believe there is a CSS solution for this. You could try some jQuery to target only Safari, get the width of div.A and use it to calculate the margin-top for div.B.

**Something like:**

```
    var width = $('.A').width();
    var topMargin = width * 0.15;
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1) {                  
        $('.B').css('margin-top', topMargin+'px')
    }
    else {
    };;
```

Here's an example page: http://www.indieweb.co.nz/testing/safari-margin-percentage.html

**Note:** This JS only alters the margin when the page is loaded - it won't change dynamically if you manually drag the edges of your browser window; you will need to refresh the page. Wasn't sure if you required that functionality. Let me know if you do and I'll have a look.

Comment: Thanks Luke. That functionality would be nice but I can just add it to  a `$(window).resize(function() {}`  function. How did you get to the value of 0.15 ?

Comment: Of course! - I missed that somehow. 0.15 multiplied by the width of div .A gives you 15% of that width. That's what you wanted yeah?

Comment: Yes i see. I have so many margins im busy writing a function to grab all the %'s from the margins and convert them. I submitted the issue to Apple, its really silly to do this.

Comment: Yeah man I totally agree - makes you wonder what went on in the safari development team that made them decide to defy the W3 standards...